# squares remaining static in newly created function

Tags: javascript

I am making a reproduction function to my game test. Inside my newly created function contains the new wolf function and subtracts the x value of the object then draws it to the canvas. The only problem is the page remains static and nothing moves. I used [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) for my research on creating new functions. Any help or feedback would be much appreciated! Heres my code

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var body = document.getElementById("body");

var wolfPop = 2;
var bornWolves = 0;

var wolves = {

};

var funs = {

};

var name;
var fname;

function setupWolf(x, y, w, h){
 context.fillStyle = "blue";
 context.fillRect(wolves[name].x, wolves[name].y, wolves[name].w, wolves[name].h);
 context.fill();
 console.log("alive wolves: " + bornWolves);
}

body.style.overflow = "hidden";
body.style.margin = "0px";
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";

setInterval(function(){
 if(wolfPop != bornWolves){
  spawnWolf();
  bornWolves++;
 }
}, 1);

function spawnWolf(){
 name = "w" + bornWolves;
 rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
 wolves[name] = Object.create({}, {x: {value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 450) + 1}, y: {value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 450) + 1}, h: {value: 10}, w: {value: 10}});
 setupWolf();
 var f1 = createWolfMove();
 f1();
}

function createWolfMove(){
 console.log("called");
 return new Function('var k = wolves[name]; setInterval(function(){ k.x -= 1; context.fillStyle = "cornflowerblue"; context.fillRect(k.x, k.y, k.w, k.h); context.fill();}, 100);');
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
<canvas id="canvas" height="500px" width="500px"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: createWolfMove is the worst way of doing sth like that. Dont use the function constructor!

Comment: What is you're suggestion then?

Comment: function wolfMove(){var k=wolves[name]; ... } ?

Comment: I might have forgotten to add this but, the reason behind creating a new function is so it can support 2 or more "wolves". Thats why I'm creating a new function

Comment: you dont need to create a new function for every wolf. Its the same for every isnt it?

Comment: no, the point of the "reproduction test" is to make new wolves, get them to move independently, and support an accurate ecological state for food and genetics

Comment: have a look at *inheritance* ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre probably looking for *inheritance* :

You could create new wolves that inherit from a wolf class:

```
 //setup canvas   
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var body = document.getElementById("body");
body.style.overflow = "hidden";
body.style.margin = "0px";
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "black";


var wolfPop = 2;
var bornWolves = 0;
var wolves = [];

function rand(a,b=1){return Math.floor(Math.random() * a) + b;}

//constructor
function Wolf(name,x,y,w,h){
 //setup 
   this.name=name||" w"+bornWolves;
   this.x=x||rand(450);
   this.y=y||rand(450);
   this.w=w||10;
   this.h=h||10;
  //update globals
  wolves.push(this);
  bornWolves++;
}
Wolf.prototype={
  update:function(){
context.fillStyle = "blue";
context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
   },
   moving:false,
   move:function(){
     this.x+=rand(100,-50);//move between 50 and -50
     this.y+=rand(100,-50);/
   }
};



setInterval(function(){
 //clear
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 //update all wolves
 wolves.forEach(function(wolf){
   if(wolf.moving) wolf.move();
   wolf.update();
 }
if(wolfPop != bornWolves){
    new Wolf();
}
}, 1);

//add a new wolf
var first=new Wolf(false,false,20,20);// a bit fater
first.moving=true;
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me code! I really needed an example because I'm new to advanced JavaScript and I thought this ecology sim would be a good practice for me, but again thank you!

Comment: @liam sperry youre welcome ;) its actually quite easy if youre through it once...